# Is this an instance of convergent evidence?

Tags: reliability, psychometrics, psychology, validity

In psychometrics, convergent validity is a source of proof for construct validity.

It is said that it is the degree to which test scores are correlated with test scores of relevant constructs or the same construct.

Suppose I have a cognitive test for working memory (construct).

Suppose I want to verify the degree of validity of the same test, but instead of being assessed by "pen and paper", it is assessed by computer.

If the results of those 2 assessments are correlated with each other, is this viewed as convergent validity?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As long as the test is the same and the only difference is how the questions are presented and how the answers are entered, this is not convergent evidence.

Otherwise any assessment can yield convergent evidence if I can administer it using pen and paper, then pencil and paper, then chalk and blackboard, then crayon and wall, etc, but the content is exactly the same each time.

Assessments of working memory that use numbers, letters, arbitrary symbols, hieroglyphics, musical notes, colors, clapping patterns, finding sets of words that rhyme in a corpus, or touching parts of the body where the answers from each medium are correlated might be considered convergent evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick pedantic point, the current language recommended in psychometrics is not to refer to proving that a test has validity but instead looking for sources of evidence for validity in various ways. One such source of validity evidence is from convergence with tests of similar constructs. In this case, evidence favoring construct validity in your computerized test may be a finding that it correlates well with other measures of working memory.

It sounds like you're really more interested in testing the psychometric equivalence of a computerized version of a test. While not a search for evidence of convergence with similar measures, the idea of psychometric equivalence between adapted versions of tests can be really useful. For example, say that you are wanting to administer a very popular and well studied working memory test while someone is in an MRI machine. In that case, a pencil-and-paper version of that test is going to be totally unhelpful, but if we know of a computer adapted version of the test that gives us equivalent results, then that is much more handy. Depending on whether you take a classical test, item response, or generalizability theory approach, there are various ways of demonstrating psychometric equivalence between two tests. You may want to just Google "test equating" or "psychometric equating" to get an idea of what might be possible for you to do.